# Any one knows what means each letter in date("l F jS Y", $timestamp) PHP?

Tags: php, function, date

I create a function in PHP to get the time, but need to know what means each letter to formatting the time :

```
$temp = "The date is : ";
echo longdate($temp, time()); 

function longdate($text, $timestamp)
{
    return $text . date("l F jS Y", $timestamp);
}
```

Comment: There's a PHP [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for that. How did you create this function then?

Comment: I took the example from other website, but thanks for the ansawer I can see in the php manual.

Comment: Do you have any specific question about this? What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**l** will output the day of the week in a word. For example, Sunday.

**F** will output the month in a word, For example, January.

**jS** will output the day as an ordinal number. For example, 15th.

**Y** will output the year using 4 digits. For example, 1993.

More information can be found in the [PHP Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [official PHP documents on date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). It gives a description of each letter and how it determines the way a date is displayed. Here is a breakdown of the letters in the date format you provided

- l — A full textual representation of the day of the week (i.e. Sunday through Saturday)
- F — A full textual representation of a month (i.e. January or March)
- j — Day of the month without leading zeros (i.e. 1 to 31)
- S — English ordinal suffix for the day of the month, 2 characters (i.e  st, nd, rd or th. Works well with j)
- Y — A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits (i.e. 1999 or 2019)